# android 4.0 webview cannot find the <a> tag

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview

html code:

```
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 38; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 1px; HEIGHT: 1px; TOP: 309px; LEFT: 431px" id=GuangBo1>
 <A onmouseover="showdiv(GuangBo)"; 
   onmouseout="closediv(GuangBo)"; 
   href="app://localhost/broadcast.do">
   <IMG src="imgs/bk.gif" width="100%" height="100%">
 </A>

</DIV>
```

in this case, browser can't find the `<a>` tag, why? the `<a>` tag lose focus cursor

Using the keyboard's arrow keys to move the focus

When I modify the `DIV`'s width & height by greater than 2px, browser find `<a>` tag is ok.

i  want to to modify webkit, but do not know how to modify

Comment: But... First: how are you doing a mouse over on Android? Next, if the DIV container is invisible (presumably since you want to show it on mouse over), how are you going to "hover" over the link (it won't be visible either)?

Comment: thanks ,Keyboard operation by LEFT，RIGHT , Etc.

Comment: Now the situation is precisely the browser that the DIV container（maybe <a> tag） is considered to invisible.I want to change this situation

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes surrounding your attributes. Correct it like this:

```
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 38; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 1px; HEIGHT: 1px; TOP: 309px; LEFT: 431px" id="GuangBo1">
 <A onmouseover="showdiv(this.parentNode);" 
   onmouseout="closediv(this.parentNode);" 
   href="app://localhost/broadcast.do">
   <IMG src="imgs/bk.gif" width="100%" height="100%">
 </A>
</DIV>
```

Also, I modified some of your code within "showdiv" and "closediv" functions, as the variables sent to them were note declared. What I added should be passing the div with the ID of "GuanBo1" to the functions.

Comment: thanks ,that was my mistake，but your answer can't solve my problem